# Nagios check_procs state filter

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to run

`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -C rsyslogd -w 1:3 -c 1:5 -s S`

and it returns

`PROCS CRITICAL: 0 processes with command name 'rsyslogd', STATE = S | procs=0;1:3;1:5;0;`

So I run with `-vvv` and find that `check_procs` uses the command `/bin/ps axwwo 'stat uid pid ppid vsz rss pcpu etime comm args'` to list processes. I find my rsyslogd process and it is listed as follows:

`Ssl    101   406     1 256232 25392  0.0 157-05:57:14 rsyslogd       rsyslogdproc#=0 uid=101 vsz=256232 rss=25392 pid=406 ppid=1 pcpu=0.00 stat=Ssl etime=157-05:57:14 prog=rsyslogd args=rsyslogd`

Looking at the help for the command it says:

`` -s, --state=STATUSFLAGS
   Only scan for processes that have, in the output of `ps`, one or
   more of the status flags you specify (for example R, Z, S, RS,
   RSZDT, plus others based on the output of your 'ps' command). ``

So it really should be working. Just for testing I tried to run

`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -C rsyslogd -w 1:3 -c 1:5 -s Ssl`

This command returns the result I expect from the first command:

`PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'rsyslogd', STATE = Ssl | procs=1;1:3;1:5;0;`

check_procs is v1.5.

I have the same test command working on a RHEL 6.5 server so it could be Ubuntu specific I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source for check_procs, the behavior you are seeing is by design. Or rather, the behavior depends entirely on the behavior of the `ps` implementation. (If it works on your RHEL system, that's almost certainly a happy coincidence.)

The plugin must use `ps` (instead of digging around in /proc) to allow it to run on systems without /proc (e.g., non-Linux).

After scraping the `ps` output, **the plugin calls `strstr` to see if the process state is contained in your command-line arg to -s**. So, in your example, it's checking to see if "Ssl" is a substring of "S".

It might seem that this is backwards logic, e.g., that it should be checking if your arg "S" is a substring of "Ssl", but I believe the intent is for you to provide multiple process states as an arg to -s.

For example, you can do this:

```
check_procs -C rsyslogd -w 1:3 -c 1:5 -s S,Ssl,Sl
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'rsyslogd', STATE = S,Ssl,Sl
```

The commas are just to make it more readable; the plugin effectively ignores them.

Comment: Very nice, I totally misunderstood the help text and the example given (that included commas). Works well on Ubuntu and RHEL now.

Comment: Link to strstr code which check if provided option to -s contains states if proc: http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-nagios/pkg-nagios-plugins.git/tree/plugins/check_procs.c?id=54238ac01fea95b8dbaab72aa478daba30882033#n268